# How to select a single text element on a page with multiple forms using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a page with multiple comment boxes. When someone clicks the submit button for the comment box JQuery handles the submission and posts the comment. I then want to set the text in the comment box back to empty. I'm using something like this:

```
$('.formstyle').submit(function() {        
    $.post("/messages/", $(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

I know there is the `.reset()` option but that still doesn't tell me how to access a single text element among many. I can use `$(":input[name=new_message]").val('');` to set the text of all the text boxes on the page but that could be annoying if someone has an message they haven't submitted. I would think something along the lines of `this.(":input[name=new_message]").val('');` would work but no dice. I think I'm just not connecting the dots between `this` (or more likely `$(this)`) and the input selector.

Comment: Are there there multiple comment boxes each in its own form with its own submit button or multiple comment boxes all in one form with one submit button?

Comment: Separate forms with separate submit buttons. I actually figured it out (after searching around _forever_) just after I submitted this question. I just passed `this` as a context to the selector and used `$("input[name=new_message]", this).val('');`. Worked like a charm. Stackexchange tells me that I can't answer my own question within 8 hours so I have to wait to close this.

Comment: Or accept one of the answers below. You may have eventually found the answer yourself, but that doesn't mean that people didn't spend time giving it to you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt : I made that comment before anyone posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this:-

```
$('.formstyle').submit(function() {        
    $.post("/messages/", $(this).serialize());
    $(this).find('input[name=new_message]').val('');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I made a small change to your answer. I added `:` to make `$(this).find(':input[name=new_message]').val('');` and it works great. Thanks for the answer, this was really bothering me.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(":input[name='new_message']",this).val('');
```

The 2nd argument for `$()` defines a context for the selector, so the selector will only match the input inside the form that fires submit

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing (mentioned in my comment above). Thanks.

Comment: Funny, when I use your solution the post only seems to work the first time. It will clear the text after that but won't submit the second comment. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my suggestion will not prevent any form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple `<form>`s, `this` will refer to the specific that's being submitted. You can use `$(this).find(':input[…]').val('')` to reset a field inside that form only.